# Solidity Transfer Token Test Case is not working fine.

Tags: solidity, remix, testing

I'm doing testing of smart contract when I try to transfer token using https://remix.ethereum.org. That was working fine. But now I want to write its test case but that is not working fine and not transferring the tokens. 
Code:

```
 it('should properly [transfer] token', async function() {
    let recipient = "0xe0f5206bbd039e7b0592d8918820024e2a7437b9";
    let tokenWei = 1000000;
    let status = await contract.methods.transfer(recipient, tokenWei).call();
    console.log(status);

    let ownerBalance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(owner).call();
    let recipientBalance = await contract.methods.balanceOf("0xe0f5206bbd039e7b0592d8918820024e2a7437b9").call();
    console.log("Balance:"+ownerBalance +'----'+recipientBalance);
  });
```

Output is like this.

```
status = true
Balance:1705243055----100000000
```

These balaces are exactly same as before mean no deduction from owner account and no addition in recipient account.

Any guidance/help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wie sendet man mit terminal? Not install senden wie?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum StackExchange. Please speak English so users could understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to use send instead of call, since you're changing the status.

```
contract.methods.transfer(recipient, tokenWei).send({from: '0x123...'})
```

Comment: Thank you, balances are showing correctly as 
1704243055-101000000
But when I tried another test case below of the test case that will show again starting assigned balance in owner account
Code
it('Owner balance', async function() {
    let Balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(owner).call();
    Balance = Balance.toString();
    console.log(Balance);
})
The output should be: 1704243055
But showing: 1705243055
So my question is there any scope issue why balance is again showing as assigned before in new test case or I need to write down one test case as I mentioned in question?

Comment: sounds strange. I don't have an answer on this it should work properly. are you using ganache-cli ?

Comment: Yes, I am using ganache-cli

Comment: Do you have an example of test cases with code? Please provide.

Comment: you can search on github something. es: https://github.com/gnosis/gnosis-contracts/tree/master/test/javascript