# Testing solidity transfer method not transferring tokens

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, testing, truffle-test

I have this solidity contract:

```
contract Token {

  mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

  event Transfer(
    address indexed _from,
    address indexed _to,
    uint256 _value
    );

  constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;
  }

  function getTokens() public returns (bool success){
    balanceOf[owner] -= 48;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += 48;
    emit Transfer(owner, msg.sender, 48);
    return true;
  }


}
```

When I run this using ganache and truffle manually, the method getTokens() works fine. I tried to write a test for it, but it does not transfer the tokens and tells me the balance of account 1 is 0.

```js
let ControlToken = artifacts.require("./ControlToken.sol");

contract('ControlToken', function (accounts) {
    it('transfers token ownership', function() {
        return ControlToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            let tokenInstance = instance;
            return tokenInstance.getTokens.call({ from: accounts[1] });
        }).then(function(success) {
            assert.equal(success, true, 'it returns true');
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[1]);
        }).then(function (balance) {
            assert.equal(balance, 48, "Balance should be 48")
        });

    });
});
```

This tests fails when i run it using truffle test. According to [Solidity Transfer Token Test Case is not working fine.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45127/solidity-transfer-token-test-case-is-not-working-fine) the problem may be that I'm using call() on getToken instead of send(), yet when i try send() the test does not recognize the command. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using truffle the correct syntax is

```
tokenInstance.getTokens({ from: accounts[1] });
```

Adding `.call()` will make the call but any change will not be recorded in the blockchain.

Comment: Well, I feel silly now! Thank you for your help!